# command line parameters for protractor to specify environment

Tags: javascript, protractor

Is there any way in protractor where we can specify environment name in command line? Based on this name i want specific URL's to be picked for test which are defined in my .env file.

Comment: I am looking for something like protractor Conf.js --Environment name --suite name

Comment: try something first, then ask questions about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the environment type while running protractor from command prompt. First you need to add params on conf.js file as shown below:

**1-on conf.js**:

```
 params: {
         environment:null
  }
```

**2-pass environment value from command prompt**

```
 protractor --params.environment='QA' conf.js
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, can you please let me know how should i capture this during scripting?
I have different URL's in .env file based on different environments? If i need to access what is entered do i need to use `if (params.environment=QA){Application URL=QA URL}else{Application URL = PreProd URL};
Let me know if this is right way to approach.

Comment: if(browser.params.environment=QA){ //write logic to assgin the url}

Comment: This is not working. var ApplicationURL = browser.params.environment;
if (ApplicationURL=="QA") {
  NewURL = process.env.QA_URL;
} else if (ApplicationURL=="staging1"){
  NewURL=process.env.Staging1_URL;
}

Comment: where do you write logic to assign the values ?

Comment: I write it before Exports.Config function of my Conf file

Comment: Do it in onPrepare as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368149/organizing-the-test-cases-for-3-environment/39372503#39372503