# Organizing the test cases for 3 environment

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

I am new to protractor. I have created my test cases for the development environment and it works fine. Now I have to move my test cases for the production and QA.

Since the code in 3 environment is same I don't want to create duplicate code for all the 3 environment.

In short If I run my code for development I should do

```
protractor conf.js -dev
```

for production

```
protractor conf.js -production.
```

-dev and -production are the respective url.
 Can anyone tell me a way I can achieve it? or should I create 3 conf.js file for the 3 environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it in as a command line option.

`protractor --baseUrl='http://www.productionUrl.com' conf.js`

Using command line arguments will also override any setting you have in your config file. So if your config file had the setting `baseUrl='http://www.test.com'`, it will take the Url you passed in the command line instead of the config file.

It's personal preference though, I myself have several config files (different browsers, environments etc).  I use the same config 95% of the time, but every once in awhile it's nice to have the others just for quick access to a specific browser/environment/whatever.  Plus I don't have to type as much :)

Comment: Hi Gunderson, I dont want the users to type the whole url that's the problem :(

Comment: Then just create separate config files.  `protractor prod.conf.js`, `protractor test.conf.js` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is, just send the environment type(QA,DEV,PROD) while running protractor from command prompt and before running, you need to add params section on conf.js file as shown below:

**1-on conf.js**:

```
 params: {
         environment:null
  }
```

**2-pass environment value from command prompt**

```
 protractor --params.environment='QA' conf.js
```

Based on environment value, you can assign the url to baseUrl parameter inside the:

```
onPrepare:function(){
   if(browser.params.environement=QA){
      browser.baseUrl="QA URL"
     }
   else{
      browser.baseUrl="PROD URL"
   }
 };
```

Comment: How to achieve the same using Angular2 CLI command `ng e2e` ?? That is passing params to `ng e2e`.